# Ошибка в коде C++

Tags: c++, c, файлы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>

int mass(float a[5][5], int *k) //функция преобразования массива
{
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    int i, j = *k, n;
    float b[5][5];

    printf("Введите степень\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(j; j < 5; j++)
        {
            fscanf(f1, "%f", &a[i][j]);
            fclose(f1);
            b[i][j] = pow(a[i][j], n);
            printf("%9.0f ", b[i][j]);

        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return i;
}

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int i, j, k = 0;
    float c[5][5];
    FILE *f1, *f2;

    f1 = fopen("FILE1.dat", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            i = mass(c, &k);

    f2 = fopen("FILE2.dat", "w");
    fclose(f2);
}
```

Идея такова: исходные данные считываются из одного файла и записываются в другой. А записи нет. Вот такая ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение в "0x7c90100b" в "lab1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xcccccd00".

Не могу понять почему, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Указатели на f1 и f2 в теле функции определены локально.
Они просто напросто =NULL.
Нужно функцию переопределить `int mass(float a[5][5],int*k,FILE*f1,FILE*f2)`,
и вызывать ее `i=mass(c,&k,f1,f2);`

Comment: 0xcccccd00 - это явно не null. А вот на дефаултное значение переменных в VS в режиме отладки очень похоже.

Answer (score 1):

> Необработанное исключение в "0x7c90100b" в "lab1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xcccccd00".

Скорее всего, в строке, на которой происходит эта ошибка, используется неинициализированный указатель.